Android Emulator - Batch Clear Location Saved Points
I am looking for a way to batch clear the "saved points" on the Android Emulator. It appears the saved points are shared across emulator instances which is fine but right now I have a ton of saved points over a long period of testing and I'd like to clear all of them.
I know I can manually click on each saved location and delete it but I have a ton and so I'm looking for a way to batch delete them.
Since the locations are shared across devices I don't believe that wiping the device will clear the saved points.
Does anyone know where these saved points are stored on disk so I can wipe them?
Thanks
Rich
